# Xcode 5 - Behaviors - processing selected text via script?

Tags: xcode, bash, xcode5

Is there a way to use a Behavior to pass the text currently selected in the IDE (i.e., a snippet of source code) to a Shell script ... and then return a value to replace the selected text with?

(I know this is possible to do with an Automator workflow, but I'd like to do it purely via the shell if possible.)

I've tried having the script look for an appropriate environment variable:

```
env > ~/xcode_behavior_env.txt
```

[There are a couple of dozen variables, but none of them correspond to the selected text.]

... examining the arguments that are passed in to the script:

```
echo '$0 = ' $0
echo '$1 = ' $1
echo '$2 = ' $2
echo '$3 = ' $3
```

[$0 is the path of the script being run; the rest are blank.]

... and using the 'read' command:

```
read foo
echo "Here's the output: $foo"
```

[Nothing at all echoes to the IDE, the Xcode console, or the Mac console (app).]

Thus, none of the above seem to work.

Is there another way to get this to work?

And for bonus karma: what, if anything, does such a script see for stdin?  And where do stdout and stderr go?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the message won't show in the console, it will show in the log.  Go:
View -> Navigator -> Show log navigator, then choose the lastest build, you will see the echoed messages